# Ionic / Angular on hover while touching / clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I am trying to mimic css :hover class on mobile. In my app you can click and drag on things, and when drag over top of elements I need those elements to get a class that changes its z-index and a few other t hings. Is it possible in Angular / Ionic or maybe just pure CSS to change style when "hovering" on touch?

I have tried adding

```
.myClass:hover{
    color:#000;
    background-color:red;
}
```

As something basic to see if it works and this works while hovering but not while clicking and hovering. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `:active`?

Comment: I have tried :active and :focus as well, they all seem to work unless I am currently holding down click / already touching.

Comment: you can combine them to all have the same effect?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I did, while I don't have the code in front of me, basically what you do is get the event gesture center x and y points, subtract half the width and height of your current element to get the center, then compare it to the bounding box of your element given by: var rect = document.getElementById("myElement").getBoundingClientRect(); it works really well and has pretty low overhead, although if you have a lot of objects it is a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add a class on touchStart and remove it on touchEnd so you can make the changes you want in the css class

Comment: Its not "on end" that I need its while I am touching. If I am currently touching AND I am hovering / over something else this needs to happen. When I let go I do not want anything to happen.

Comment: yes, thats it. When you start the touch you have to add a class, for example an "active" class, so you will add a z-index and a different style, and when you touch is end you remove the class.